# Why my project won't get deployed to wildfly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, jboss7.x

*I'm trying to deploy my project but i get this error. I assumed my dependencies are incompatible with my project so i upgraded them and yet it didn't work. Another attempt i checked the class itself and it shows no error.

```
 Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component MessageMappingRegistrator
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not \"opens java.lang\" to unnamed module @44c8f505"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService","jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"message_rest_servicesss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService]"]}
```

Here is my class MessageMappingRegistrator

```
package org.example.entity.registrator;


import org.example.entity.MessageMapping;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Stateless
public class MessageMappingRegistrator {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void create(MessageMapping item) {
        logger.info( "Created message mapping: " + item);
        entityManager.merge(item);
    }


        public void update(MessageMapping item){
            logger.info("Updated message mapping: " + item);
            entityManager.merge(item);
        }


    public void delete (MessageMapping item){
        logger.info("Deleted message mapping: " + item);
        entityManager.remove(item);
        }
}
```

*Any idea!!! thanks in advance*

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: EAP-7.3.0 @JamesR.Perkins

Comment: Does `org.example.entity.MessageMapping` implement cloneable?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins i used java 18 and actually am required to use java 9(Currently using ).Now the error am getting "javax.xml.bind.JAXBException" which obviously means javax is missing. I added this dependency it didn't fix the error. Ill share my POM.xml  in my next post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179824/why-maven-wont-deploy-my-project-and-how-can-i-fix-this-issue