# Why maven won't deploy my project and how can i fix this issue?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

**Am using JBOSS EAP-7.3.0
java 9**
If we assume the "javax" dependency which is currently called "jakarta" is the one to be  used it with it's latest version it didn't solve the problem. Feels like no matter what version of javax i add it won't work!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
        Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
        contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
        distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
    
        Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
        you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
        You may obtain a copy of the License at
        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
    -->
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssggg</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>WildFly Quickstarts: mssggg</name>
        <description>A starter Java EE 7 webapp project for use on JBoss WildFly / WildFly, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>
    
        <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
                <distribution>repo</distribution>
                <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
            </license>
        </licenses>
    
        <properties>
            <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
                message: -->
            <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
                resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
            <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
            <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    
            <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify 
                tested stacks. -->
            <version.jboss.bom>8.2.1.Final</version.jboss.bom>
    
            <!-- other plugin versions -->
            <version.compiler.plugin>3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
            <version.surefire.plugin>2.16</version.surefire.plugin>
            <version.war.plugin>3.3.2</version.war.plugin>
    
            <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        </properties>
    
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 7 APIs including a Bill
                    of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection) 
                    of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions 
                    of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools stack (you can
                    read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with some extras tools
                    for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate
                    stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 7 APIs, with extras
                    from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <dependencies>
    
            <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All 
                of them are provided by JBoss WildFly -->
    
            <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
                JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope 
                as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
                in JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
                JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
                JBoss WildFly -->
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
            <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
            <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in 
                JBoss WildFly -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->
    
            <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for 
                typesafe criteria queries -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever constraint 
                annotations are incorrectly used. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
            <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) 
                JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
            <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
            <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name 
                given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- The WildFly plugin deploys your war to a local WildFly container -->
                <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                        <port>9990</port>
                        <username>admin</username>
                        <password>*******</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run 
                    just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
                <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian 
                    tests that execute in the specified container -->
                <id>default</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>true</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
    
            <profile>
    
                <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                    in your WildFly instance -->
                <!-- This profile will start a new WildFly instance, and execute the
                    test, shutting it down when done -->
                <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-managed -->
                <id>arq-wildfly-managed</id>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </profile>
    
            <profile>
                <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests
                    in a remote WildFly instance -->
                <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-wildfly-remote -->
                <id>arq-wildfly-remote</id>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </profile>
    
            <profile>
                <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                    invoking mvn. -->
                <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                    will need. -->
                <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                    folder. -->
                <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
                <id>openshift</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                                <warName>ROOT</warName>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
    
        </profiles>
    </project>
```

After using

> mvn clean

no errors is showing

> mvn install

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project mssggg: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ja
    vax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
```

> mvn wildfly:deploy

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project mssggg: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ja
        vax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Java 9 hasn't been supported in over 4 years.  I'd work with something more supported.

Answer (score 1):

You're using version 4.0.0 of JAXB, which is too new since in version 3.0 classes were moved from javax.xml.* to the new jakarta.xml.* packages.

Try version 2.3.0. You may also want to take a look at this [comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/19654754).

Comment: I Fixed the problem turns out i accidently removed the a file that uses JAXB.